# Simple SQLServer PIVOT/Transposed query, how to write?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a SELECT which is returning me data in the following form...

```
ID             Question             Answer
1              Any Good?            Yes
1              Happy?               No
1              Good Staff?          Yes
1              Return?              N/A
2              Any Good?            No
2              Happy?               No
2              Good Staff?          Yes
2              Return               N/A
...
```

I need this in the following form...

```
ID       Any Good?   Happy?   Good Staff?   Return?
1        Yes         No       Yes           N/A
2        No          No       Yes           N/A
...
```

The 'Answer' column in my top query is computed using a `CASE .. WHEN`. I was thinking maybe the `PIVOT` clause could help me. This seems to require aggregation though. I don't need to aggregate, just transpose.

I don't mind having to specify each `Answer` explicitly in the solution (I'm guessing I'll have to do that anyway).

Anyone know the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  ID,
                    Question,
                    Answer
            FROM    @Table1
        ) t
PIVOT (MAX(Answer) FOR Question IN ([Any Good?],[Happy?],[Good Staff?],[Return?])) p
```

Answer (score 1):

The pivot operation requires you to use some form of aggregate, however if you will only have one value `Max()` will grab the max (only) value for you

Something Like this should work

```
Select *
from Table
Pivot
(
    Max(answer)
    For Question In ([Any Good?],[Happy?],[Good Staff?],[Return?])
)
AS P
```