# adding more Columns based on number of years

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, crosstab

Using Sql server 2008
So i have a queried table that looks like this in the end

Example:

```
month    Year    data
1        2012     123
...      2012     123
12       2012     123
1        2013     123
...      2013     123
12       2013     123
```

Is there a way to do a select on it so that it would come out like this

```
month    Year    data    month    Year    data
1        2012     123      1      2013     123
...      2012     123      ...    2013     123
12       2012     123      12     2013     123
```

Basically adding a new row of columns for each new year it returns

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (PostgreSQL? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?)

Comment: sorry edited the question also. sql server 2008

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple SQLServer PIVOT/Transposed query, how to write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104187/simple-sqlserver-pivot-transposed-query-how-to-write)

Answer (score 1):

That's much easier to do client-side, in `C#` or PHP or Python.  But it can be done in SQL:

```
select  month as Month2012
,       2012 as Year2012
,       max(case when year = 2012 then data end) as Data2012
,       month as Month2013
,       2013 as Year2013
,       max(case when year = 2013 then data end) as Data2013
,       month as Month2014
,       2014 as Year2014
,       max(case when year = 2014 then data end) as Data2014
,       ...
from    YourTable
group by
        month
```